# Entity Framework 6: Suppressing divide by zero exceptions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I would like to make something like this work with entity framework:

```
db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.MoneySpent/c.OrdersPlaced)
```

without having to put any sort of divide by zero protection like this:

```
db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.OrdersPlaced == 0 ? 0.0 : c.MoneySpent/c.OrdersPlaced)
```

In order to do that, I tried a couple of things, but the closest I got was to solving the problem was to disable `ARITHABORT` and `ANSI_WARNINGS`, which I did in my context's constructor:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    static DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("Name=DatabaseContext")
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ANSI_DEFAULTS OFF");
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT OFF");
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF");
    }

    // Tables that can be queried directly
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

When I then try to get the results from my Web API controller, I still get the following error:

```
...failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json...
InnerException: Divide by zero error encountered...
```

When I take a look at what's going on with the SQL Server Profiler, it seems as though `ANSI_WARNINGS` is reset to `ON` whenever a new query is made.

[image: SQL Server Profiler]

Is there a way to perhaps change the default value of `ANSI_WARNINGS` so that it stays `OFF` between queries?

Comment: What's wrong with the first way you did it?  That's pretty standard divide-by-zero handling.

Comment: I know... but I'm exploring something different, mainly suppressing those errors, even if that means it's bad practice.

Comment: Bad practice, hard to debug, outside the application's control, etc.  You might find a way to do it but it's a design smell IMHO.

Comment: Fair advice, I really do appreciate it, but the question is still valid. I guess I'll just have to dig more.

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, you could try setting the default value of ANSI_WARNINGS within SQL:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368(v=sql.110).aspx/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that the scope of the `ARITHABORT` and `ANSI_WARNINGS` commands is limited to the transaction.

> Starting with EF6 `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` by default will wrap
>   the command in a transaction if one was not already present

You will either have to set the database default - (and accept all the implications that might have!)

> You can use the user options option of sp_configure to set the default
>   setting for ANSI_WARNINGS for all connections to the server. For more
>   information, [see sp_configure (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx/css).

Or you will have to manage your own connection/transaction using EF6's [improved transaction support](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Improved%20Transaction%20Support)

Either way it seems like a lot of work to avoid coding for divide by zero....

References:

[Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn456843)

[SET ANSI_WARNINGS (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx)

Comment: I know I could get killed for getting that idea, but let's assume that I'm a master at security, and that I've made my code foolproof. Let's say I wanted to let my users pass custom expressions (MoneySpent/OrdersPlaced) to my Web API so that they can order the customers in any way they want. I could parse those expressions and feed them to Dynamic Linq. I that case, I could either dynamically insert divide by zero protection or turn off the exceptions, and the latter just seemed easier to me.

Comment: @Deli that sounds like fun! Let's just agree that you have a legitimate reason to change a database setting for the duration of a transaction - EF6 now gives you the control over transactions that you need

Answer (score 1):

With Colin's great answer, I was able to implement the following controller, and it now works perfectly fine! Thanks!

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly CutomerContext _context = new CustomerContext();
    private DbContextTransaction _transactionContext;

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
    {
        _transactionContext = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();

        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF");
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT OFF");

        var orderedCustomers = _context.Customers.OrderByDescending(c => ((double)c.MoneySpent)/c.OrdersPlaced);

        return orderedCustomers.AsEnumerable();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        if(_transactionContext != null)
            _transactionContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the setting being reset in each query may have to do with the fact that EF will by default open and close the connection on  each query. You can override the behavior by opening the connection manually.

Anyway, I agree with this doesn't sound like a robust approach.

A better way to deal with this maybe to make sure OrdersPlaced will be NULL instead of zero (x / NULL won't cause an error but will evaluate to NULL).

Comment: 0 is a perfectly valid value for OrdersPlaced if someone has placed no orders, though. NULL would be weird there: the field applies to that customer, and you know exactly how many orders have been placed. I generally don't consider it a good idea to make data in the database hard to understand.